# iPhone XS Max running 13.5.1 notification issue

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, apns

I realize this is not really the kind of question for a SE site and I do apologize but I've looked elsewhere and can't seem to find anything so I'm desperate.

Tapping on a notification for a received message, whether in the banner, lock screen, or notification center, will only open the Messages app but not the actual received message.

Is this a known issue? Is there a resolution?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Of course there is. It is implied, obviously. How is this issue resolved?

Comment: Does a 3D Touch open a small messages preview sort of thing where you can reply? A 3D Touch is pressing with more force on the Notification just in case you didn't know.

Comment: @Todd yes it does.